# problem with datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i have a php code like this:

```
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
    $date =date( "Y-m-d H:i:s");
    echo $date;
```

output is

```
2011-05-01 11:31:49
```

but when insert **$date** in `Datetime` column date is
  2011-05-01 11:05:07

INSERT CODE:

```
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $date=date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
    $q="insert into TABLE values
    ('$date')";
mysql_query($q);
```

why?

Comment: What exactly do you insert into your database? And did you check the time settings of the mysql server?

Comment: check the time settings of the mysql server? how?

Comment: it return same time with windows time. mysql server is localhost

Comment: Are you physically in GMT? Also, please let us know what your query looks like.

Comment: Show your query, so we could see if there is any problems with it/

Comment: i m not physically in GMT and try my timezone too.

Comment: Can you do a test output of `$date` before you insert it into the table? Are both scripts running on the same server?

Comment: That's still not your query, table is a reserved work so you've just written a fake query for us to see what you did. But if you have an error in your true code, we won't be able to see it ;)

Comment: i should set timezone for mysql seperately?

Comment: i replace $date with NOW() and  datetime  is same with windows time but $date is not same with windows time (6 minute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example uses `$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` which seems ok.

Your second example uses `$date=date("Y-m-d H:m:s");` which seems strange, you're using the month(m) in the conversion for minutes.